# Phone wont respond

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I have a Microsoft phone.

After leaving it for a while, the screen goes black and only the time shows (normal / expected behaviour).

If the screen has been black for a little while (about a minute), the phone wont respond to anything.

The time is frozen at the point it stopped responding.

The only thing I seem to be able to do is hold the power button down until the device resets. Then the phone works fine, until the black screen shows again.

What can I do to stop this?

Comment: please mention your os.

Comment: its in my tags - windows 10

Comment: i meant the build too, redstone or threshold, because redstone is very buggy

Comment: how do i discover this information?

Comment: settings->system->about-> click 'more info' where you'll find OS build number.